# SPF2013 - Search doesn’t return anything

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

I have a **SharePoint 2013 Foundation on a Windows Server 2012 R2** and when I use `search box` in a site collection to search an document then nothing is returned, even though that document exists in the site collection.

I have the default `Search Service Application` created after the SharePoint installation.

In the Central Administration, when I go to **Content Sources**, there is no error when I do a **Full crawl**. I wait for few more minutes but nothing is found.

In the crawl log, columns named **Successes**, **Errors**, etc., each one are **0**.

I don’t know why *nothing is found*. The user I use to crawl is **sp-admin** and it has rights to read everything (or that’s what I think).

The URL I have set up to crawl is the URL of the `Web Application` (let’s say: http://sharepoint), in order to crawl every `site collection`.

I have no idea why this is happening. I know that this feature is **available in 2013 Foundation** but I don’t know why it doesn’t work for me. I have googled but I don’t find anything about this.

- First of all, what should I check in order to know that I have everything correct set up?
- Second, if I have everything “correct”, how and where can I see what is error or failing?

Thank you!

Comment: Whats the crawl account you are using? Make sure it has read access to the web app and also  try browsing your site with that account , just to ensure the permissions are properly setup

Comment: @GauravVijh The crawl account I'm using is an administrator account called "sp-admin". I have already given it read access to web app, logged in as "sp-admin" in Administration, start full crawling, but nothing found :/. Please, if you need some screenshot just ask me. I still don't get why it doesn't work.

Comment: what authentication you are using in default zone? check the event log and ULS logs for more clue? make sure Search related services are running.